# combine 2 values in json foreach

Tags: php

I am pulling info from a json file

> json raw

```
{
  "channels": [    
    {
      "position": 2,
      "id": "411322093804978180",
      "name": "Home"
    },
    {
      "position": 0,
      "id": "411324510143381505",
      "name": "Lobby"
    }
  ],


  "members": [

    {
      "username": "John", 
      "channel_id": "411324510143381505",     
      "id": "408129022657036454"
    },    
    {
      "username": "Ted", 
      "id": "320056690290458665"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Home Server"
}
```

I am able to get the channel name to show  but if a user is not in a channel then they have no channel id if you look at the member part of the json. but if they are in a channel it adds the channel_id to the members part of the json that id matches the channels id so im trying to shows the users that have a channel_id inside the channel there in by doing if channels id equals user channel id

with the following but its not adding the users to channel

```
foreach($result['channels'] as $item){     

   echo '<div class="channel">
           <div class="channel-name">'.$item['name'].'</div>';           

          if ($result['channels']['id'] == $result['members']['channel_id']){
              echo $result['members']['username'];
          } else {
              echo '';
          }




   echo '</div>';

}
```

Comment: `$result['channels']` and `$result['members']` are both arrays, and will never have indices `'id'` or `'channel_id'`.

Comment: the channels has an id that matches channel id if the user is in that channel

Comment: You didn't understand my comment. Do a `var_export($result['channels'])` and `var_export($result['channels']['id'])` and you will see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue the way you started, for each channel you have to check every user :

```
foreach($result['channels'] as $item){     
   echo '<div class="channel">
           <div class="channel-name">'.$item['name'].'</div>';           

          foreach($result['members'] as $member){   
            if(isset($member['channel_id']) && !strcmp($member['channel_id'], $item['id'])) {
                echo $member['username'];
            }
          }

   echo '</div>';
}
```

Is this what you want ?

Doc :
https://php.net/strcmp
https://php.net/isset